# C# OpenGL draw quadrangle using GL_QUADS

Tags: c#, opengl

I have got some problem with drawing quadrangles in OpenGL using GL_QUADS. I have the list with points. Each point has x,y,z.

I know that to draw quadrangles I NEED order as fallow:

1. top left
2. bottom left
3. top right
4. bottom right.

The problem is that, I didnt know which point is top left, bottom left etc.,  beacouse coordinates of each point are calculated in other method. Is there any method (C#) or algorithm that can help me designate which point is top left ect ?

Comment: You'd save yourself alot of trouble if you make the other method (if possible) output the points in a known order.

Comment: It is impossible. I break tetrahedron into 4 triangles. In this triangles I set points. I cant say, which triangle is "first", "second" etc. Iam sure, that calculated points are good, but I dont have right order in list..

Comment: If you know what directions (x,y, or whatever) top, bottom, left and right are you could try to separate the two leftmost from the rightmost and the two topmost from the two bottom ones if the data is "nice" and allows that. In general i agree with @Chris.